# Iframe change select option texts

Tags: javascript, jquery

The **"when page loads"** part of the code works fine.

The **"When selection is made"** part of the code works but seems to stop after a couple of selection changes. Would like it to work on both select boxes as many times as the user changes the selections.

https://jsfiddle.net/czqpkL6j/1/

```
 //when page loads 
setTimeout(function() {           
      var iframePreLoad = $("#product-component-1635439141053").children().contents();
      iframePreLoad.find(".shopify-buy__option-select__select").ready(function(){
        iframePreLoad.find('select[name=Color] option:nth-child(1)').html('Black');  
        iframePreLoad.find('select[name=Color] option:nth-child(2)').html('Green');
      }); 

//When selection is made
       iframePreLoad.find('select').on('change', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            iframePreLoad.find('select[name=Color] option:nth-child(1)').html('Black');  
          iframePreLoad.find('select[name=Color] option:nth-child(2)').html('Green');
        },100)
         

        console.log('selection changed');
       });
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what's the surrounding here exactly but a wild guess based on experience: do the elements potentially change after the `iframePreLoad.find(..)` selector resolved? If so, nodes matching the selector won't be in the result set (for obvious reasons) and thus have no `change` handler attached.

The usual approach to problems like this is to make use of event bubbling and attach the listener to a container surrounding the elements you want to observe. That way you will catch events even from elements changed or added afterwards.

Comment: Fantastic tip. I attached the change listener to a container surrounding the target select element. Works great! https://jsfiddle.net/fxe8j2y9/